# df.to_sql error : 'h' format requires -32768 <= number <= 32767

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to ingest a dataframe to postgres db using python script in AWS Glue. It processes some dataframes, but for some dataframes, while doing `df.to_sql` it gives

```
'h' format requires -32768 <= number <= 32767
```

If someone has experience with such kind of error, inputs are welcome. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It's not error in postgres table that's for sure, because code is running fine on local machine.

Comment: Can you provide enough code to reproduce what you're doing? And a sample of the data

Answer (score 0):

'h' is stored with a [*smallint* on 2 bytes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) (-32768 to +32767).

You must ensure that the column holding your hours are within those bounds.

If you originally have integers, you can use [`clip(-32768, 32767)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) to enforce those limits, or drop the invalid data.

Comment: Hi, What does this 'h' mean in the error? I need to know it to narrow down the source of error. I have added screenshot to the question as to what data actually looks like. All i am  doing is to insert this data in a table. I tried to typecast complete dataframe to string type to avoid this range issue, but no luck. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Probably 'hour'? can you bisect the columns to determine a minimal dataframe that produces the error?

Comment: It sometimes work for such dataframes, sometimes it's erroring out. For now I have relied on using INSERT INTO equivalent from this dataframe due to urgency, but i'll explore it. Thanks for your help.